# Using Rules after importing an item using Feeds to set a custom field value

Tags: rules, feeds

I need a bit of help with Feeds and Rules. I have a Feed Importer that uses XPATH to parse websites for Titles and creates nodes in a custom content type. I've added a field (Field_Source) to the content type. What I'd like to do is create a rule to copy the Feed URL value into the Field_Source. I have a new rule that acts on After importing Feed but I'm not able to get access to the fields in the Node.

If I change the Event to Before saving an item imported by Feeds, I can get access to the node:field_source but not the Feeds URL.

SOLVED: It was much easier than this: I just added a relationship in Views to the Feed Item and was able to use the source URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Feeds Tamper.](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) do do what you want...i.e. map the pertinent section from your source "Feed URL" to your 'field_source' and then use feeds tamper to shape it up as you like...

Comment: Rules should be a plugin for the Feeds module right. I'm not able to see this option under the Tamper section. I just downloaded Drupal a week ago and installed all new modules including Feeds module as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: Rules is separate module from Feeds tamper.

Comment: I mean apart from the normal Rules, I want to be able to map Drupal taxonomies to a feeded item and currently tamper feed does not have this ability. Only basic string manipulations. Nothing that will read taxonomies on-the-fly.